# Getting STDIN in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, stdin

I need to write a code for competition using STDIN and STDOUT, how can I set up eclipse to take input from STDIN??

When I was just using editor and command line I was running:

```
java Hatch < hatch_input
```

Now I need the equivalent to work directly from eclipse. It would be perfect if I could use it directly from file, but it would to suffice to just be able to paste the actual input somewhere, as long as I can write code that takes STDIN directly in eclipse by clicking RUN.

```
class Main{

       public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

}
```

Above code is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean that in the Argument tab of Run Configuration, you may type exactly : <  hatch_input   (with hatch_input being a file name) ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your program you can setup a run configuration. Just click on on the arrow next to the play button and choose "Run configurations..."

In the new run configuration dialog you create a new Java application run configuration. In the tab "Arguments" you can enter the arguments you want the program to receive.

Suggestion: In the last tab, "common", choose to save it as a shared file, this will create a *.launch file that you can use to quickly run the program. You can also create different launch files for different inputs.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just type in the input data or copy paste in the console window of the eclipse. for Sdtin when the program hits that point focus shifts to console and waits for the response.

Comment: how can you specify that you have finished with the stdin? Let´s say you have:  while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {...}   and you want to type a few strings on the console, and then move on with the execution. In my case, I can type in the console, but the program never moves on to the next line.

Comment: once you finished typing in the console just press enter without anything then !StdIn.isEmpty() will be false and it will exit the loop. After you can move on with rest of the program.

Comment: Ctrl + D works more reliably than checking for an empty string (which assumes you're parsing by line)

Answer (score 0):

There is following code,which i tried. this code is working fine if you run program in command prompt, but in eclipse not working because there console are no longer waiting for user input and give the `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

if you are read data by user input you can use `System.in.read()`. and this is also working in eclipse console.

In this code you can get Data from user but this data is not `args` which we throw at run time...

```
public class CONSOLE
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Console c = System.console();

        System.out.println("Enter Username : \t");
        String u = c.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Password : \t");
        char[] p = c.readPassword();

        System.out.println("USERNAME : "+u);
        System.out.println("PASSWORD : "+String.valueOf(p));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=sc.nextLine();
```